# Null Reference error using nServiceBus and AzureDataBus

Tags: c#, nservicebus

**Edit** This is not a duplicate question I am asking about a null reference exception in a third party component.

I have a databus configured as:

```
var config = new BusConfiguration();
config.AssembliesToScan(typeof(XXXXX).Assembly);

config.UseContainer<NinjectBuilder>((c)=>c.ExistingKernel(this.Kernel));
config.UsePersistence<RavenDBPersistence>();
config.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();
config.UseSerialization<XmlSerializer>();
config.EnableInstallers();


var databus=config.UseDataBus<AzureDataBus>();
databus.ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["DataBus"].ConnectionString);


config.Conventions().
        DefiningDataBusPropertiesAs(p => p.Name == "Data" && p.PropertyType == typeof(Byte[]));


    var bus = NServiceBus.Bus.CreateSendOnly(config);
```

I have a message class as:

```
public class FileDeliveryMessage : ICommand
{

    public Byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public Guid WorkId { get; set; }
    public int ReportId { get; set; }

    public int Extension { get; set; }
    public int FileType { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I send a message I get a null reference error. This error occurs on the send not with the handlers

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   NServiceBus.DataBusSendBehavior.Invoke(OutgoingContext context, Action
>   next) in
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\DataBus\DataBusSendBehavior.cs:line
>   51    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0() in
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   95    at
>   NServiceBus.PopulateAutoCorrelationHeadersForRepliesBehavior.Invoke(OutgoingContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Sagas\PopulateAutoCorrelationHeadersForRepliesBehavior.cs:line
>   47    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0() in
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   95    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at
>   NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0() in
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   95    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.InvokeNext(T context) in
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   107    at NServiceBus.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   52    at
>   NServiceBus.Pipeline.PipelineExecutor.Execute[T](BehaviorChain`1
>   pipelineAction, T context) in
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\PipelineExecutor.cs:line
>   129    at
>   NServiceBus.Pipeline.PipelineExecutor.InvokeSendPipeline(DeliveryOptions
>   deliveryOptions, LogicalMessage message) in
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\PipelineExecutor.cs:line
>   116    at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendMessage(SendOptions
>   sendOptions, LogicalMessage message) in
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line
>   610

Comment: This is not a duplicate, thanks! If it is link me to the answer and I will honor your google-fu skills as being superior to mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was occuring because, I was only including my own assemblies to be scanned:

config.AssembliesToScan(typeof(XXXXX).Assembly);

Changes to:

```
        IIncludesBuilder includesBuilder = AllAssemblies
                                            .Matching("NServiceBus")
                                            .And("XXXX.XXX");


        config.AssembliesToScan(includesBuilder);
```

Comment: I would suggest to change your strategy on assembly scanning and use exclusion list rather than inclusion list. Inclusion list is much more difficult to get right and it's fragile. When adding new things, it needs to be constantly updated. With exclusion list you only list things you know for sure need to be excluded, so additions are not forcing you to review that list each time. 
In addition to that, inclusion API will be deprecated in the future because of this problematic behaviour, so you could already start migrating.

Comment: Here's documentation: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/assembly-scanning